# How do I create a callback function with ctypes in Python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wrote a wrapper for the Corsair Utility Engine SDK, but there is one function that I have not been able to wrap. It's an async function that accepts a callback function, but I cannot seem to figure out how to give it that callback.

The function looks like this:

```c
bool CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync(int size, CorsairLedColor* ledsColors, void (*CallbackType)(void* context, bool result, CorsairError error), void *context)
```

These are the implementations that I have tried so far:

```py
def SetLedsColorsAsync(self, size, led_color, callback, context):
    c_func = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_void_p, c_bool, c_int)
    c_callback = c_func(callback)
    self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.restype = c_bool
    self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(CorsairLedColor), c_void_p, c_void_p]
    return self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync(size, led_color, c_callback, context)
```

as well as

```py
def SetLedsColorsAsync(self, size, led_color, callback, context):
    c_func = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_bool, c_int)
    c_callback = c_func(callback)
    self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.restype = c_bool
    self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(CorsairLedColor), c_func, c_void_p]
    return self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync(size, led_color, c_callback, context)
```

The code I'm testing with is

```py
from cue_sdk import *
import time


def test(context, result, error):
    print context, result, error
    return 0

Corsair = CUE("CUESDK.x64_2013.dll")
Corsair.RequestControl(CAM_ExclusiveLightingControl)
Corsair.SetLedsColorsAsync(1, CorsairLedColor(CLK_H, 255, 255, 255), test, 1)

while True:
time.sleep(1)
```

The `time.sleep()` is there just to keep the program alive.

When running it, it crashes with error code `3221225477` (`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`) on Windows.

[If you need to see the actual wrapper, you can find it here](https://github.com/10se1ucgo/cue_sdk/tree/master/cue_sdk).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: How do you define `CallbackType`?

Comment: @tynn [This is the documentation for the function](http://i.imgur.com/ZRsrSPW.png), CallbackType isn't mentioned anywhere else in the manual.

Comment: I'm asking for your python code `c_callback = CallbackType(callback)`

Comment: @tynn Ah, that was a mistake, I've edited my original post. It should've been `c_callback = c_func(callback)`. My bad.

Comment: The second one looks correct to me. `test` shouldn't return anything though. Maybe you should elaborate, what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @tynn It crashes with error code `3221225477` (`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`) on Windows. I'll add that to the original post as well.

Comment: "Async" in the name implies that the operation is carried out asynchronously. In that case, you don't know when the callback will be called, and it must not be deallocated until then. I suggest you create a permanent callback as a class attribute. To handle the user's callable, you can store a dict in the class that maps it to a unique ID, e.g. `id(callback)`. Pass this ID as the context value. Then when the permanent callback is called, it can use the ID as a key to pop the user's callable from the dict and call it.

Comment: BTW, `_libcue` and all of the function prototypes should be defined only once at either the module or class level. It's a waste of time to do this for every instance and method call.

Comment: To support a context parameter for the user's callback function, you can use a tuple such as `user_context = (callback, context)`. Use the ID of this tuple as the key in the class callback mapping, and pass this ID as the callback context, e.g. `context = id(user_context);` `self._callback_map[context] = user_context`. Then the permanent callback can use the ID to pop the tuple with the user's callback and context parameter.

Comment: @eryksun Ah, I completely forgot about garbage collection. I'll try this out. Thanks for the help! And yes, it seems like a nightmare.

Comment: @eryksun It worked! Thanks so much for your help. You should submit it as an answer so I can mark it. I can do it if you don't want to.

Comment: If you have a tested, working solution, write it up as an answer.

Comment: @eryksun Done! Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot about the issue with garbage collection until eryksun reminded me. He suggested that I create a permanent callback handler that would store all of the callbacks and call + pop them when necessary. This is what I did.

The function prototype looks like this:

```py
self._callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_bool, c_int)
self._callback = self._callback_type(self._callback_handler)
self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.restype = c_bool
self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(CorsairLedColor), self._callback_type, c_void_p]
```

The `_callback_handler` function looks like this:

```py
def _callback_handler(self, context, result, error):
    if context is not None and context in self._callbacks:
        self._callbacks.pop(context)(context, result, error)
```

The actual function looks like this.

```py
def SetLedsColorsAsync(self, size, led_color, callback=None, context=None):
    if callback:
        if context is None:
            context = id(callback)
        self._callbacks[context] = callback
    return self._libcue.CorsairSetLedsColorsAsync(size, led_color, self._callback, context)
```

`_callback_type` is the actual CFUNCTYPE that wraps the permanent callback (`_callback_handler`) which is one of the prototype's argtype. When `SetLedsColorsAsync` is called, the `callback` parameter is put into a dictionary (with the context or the ID of the function being the key). Instead of supplying the callback into the function, the permanent callback is passed on instead. Once the permanent callback is called, it will call the proper function and remove it from the dictionary.

The test I used:

```py
#!python3
import time

from cue_sdk import *


def test(context, result, error):
    print(context, result, error)
    assert context == id(test)


Corsair = CUE("CUESDK.x64_2013.dll")
Corsair.RequestControl(CAM_ExclusiveLightingControl)
Corsair.SetLedsColorsAsync(1, CorsairLedColor(CLK_H, 255, 255, 255), test)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Example output:

```py
2969710418936 True 0
```

[If I'm not making sense, the commit is here.](https://github.com/10se1ucgo/cue_sdk/commit/ab71b4414d859e361a85d925d0e3b936bb1622c0)

Comment: The user `context` may not be unique. I suggest creating a `(callback, context)` tuple and setting its `id` as `context`. The permanent callback will then `pop` and unpack the tuple.

Comment: The optimization to pass the context as `NULL` (`None`) when the user doesn't provide a `callback` is good, but it needs error checking.  Early exceptions will be clearer than asynchronous exceptions in the permanent callback. If `callback` is `None`, then raise `ValueError` if `context` isn't also `None`. Else raise `TypeError` if `not callable(callback)`. Otherwise store the tuple in `_callbacks` by its `id`, which becomes the `context` for the permanent callback.

Comment: I also suggest storing `_libcue`, `_callback`, and `_callbacks` on the class itself. There's no reason to set these on every instance.

Comment: @eryksun Do you mean setting them as static elements of the class? All three of them are defined in `__init__`. I'll implement your first two suggestions, however.

Comment: Yes, set them as class attributes defined in the body of the class. You can still refer to them using `self` from an instance method. Also, all of the prototypes should be defined only once after creating `_libcue`. That way you're not redefining the prototype every time a method is called. I'd loop over a list defined in the module level that has each function name and prototype (error check function, result type, and argument types). Given the name, get the function pointer dynamically via `func = getattr(_libcue, name)`. Then assign its `errcheck`, `restype`, and `argtypes` attributes.